# SED command gives unknown option to `s' error

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file like this:

```
1 = zara
2 = gucci
```

I want to write a bash script which read two variables and decides to change the number in one of lines to a new number. I have this script for this purpose:

```
pattern="$num[[:space:]]=[[:space:]].*"
sed -ie 's,'"$pattern"','"$num"',\ =\ '"$newBrandName"',' $fileLocation
```

Variables `num`, `newBrandName` and `fileLocation` have the right value; I have checked this by `echo` command.

But when I run the script, I get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 52: unknown option to `s'
```

The output of `echo` on the SED command is this:

```
sed -ie s,1[[:space:]]=[[:space:]].*,1\ =\ sign, /root/info.info
```

Can anyone help me with the regex?

Comment: Could you echo the full sed command ? eg:

Comment: @tripleee, I didn't find anything related to my question from the your suggested link.

Comment: @NoDataFound, could you please explain me how to get the echo of the sed command?

Comment: Huh? You already have two separate replies explaining the issue.

Comment: Just put "echo" before the command. That's what I do to get the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If think it's because you have an extraneous `,` left :

```
pattern="$num[[:space:]]=[[:space:]].*"
sed -ie 's,'"$pattern"','"$num"',\ =\ '"$newBrandName"',' $fileLocation
--------------------------------^
```

You might consider escaping it, or use another character like `@`.

Comment: Thank you; removing the character solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The form of `s` is `s/regexp/replacement/`. You can't have multiple expressions on it. Try this instead:

```
sed -i -e '/^${num}[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*/s|.*|$num = $newBrandName|" "$fileLocation"
```

It would find the line matching `^${num}[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*` and replace everything on it with `$num = $newBrandName`.

You also should separate `-i` and `-e` so `e` would not be interpreted as the backup suffix for `-i`.

Comment: it gives me this:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 62: unknown option to `s'
`

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi What was the command you used?

Comment: I used this: `sed -i -e '/^${num}[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*/s|.*|$num = $newBrandName|" "$fileLocation"'`